# Irrlicht Mac OS X crash

Tags: c++, macos, irrlicht

I'm trying to get Irrlicht running on Mac OS X, but when I try to run the "Demo" project, I see a screen with some options, but as soon as I click something, I get a lldb error for the following line of code:

```
[Window setIsVisible:FALSE];
```

It's line 554 of file CllrDeviceMacOSX.mm, and it gives this error in about every example I try to run

My system:

- MacBook Pro Retina late 2012
- Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Comment: ... and what *kind* of error might it be? There are many kinds of crashes.

Comment: I get a EXC_BAD_ACCES error, BTW, none of the GUI controls actually work, except from the "start demo" button, but when I click it, I get the error too

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the NSWindow object `Window` is being released before the call to `[Window setIsVisible:FALSE];`.

Looking at Apple's documentation ([NSWindow isReleasedWhenClosed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_123)) this is the expected behaviour as by default NSWindow objects are automatically released when closed.

As a workaround add:

```
[Window setReleasedWhenClosed:FALSE];
```

after the `Window = [[NSWindow alloc].....` calls in CllrDeviceMacOSX.mm (there are two of them). I do not know enough about Irrlicht to know if this is a valid fix.

Comment: I have submitted a ticket to the Irrlicht project, [bug #426](https://sourceforge.net/p/irrlicht/bugs/426/).